# Enabling my disabled app programmatically

Tags: android, eclipse

I was just checking package manager functions and i used its function setApplicationEnabledSetting ( pkgName , *_disabled , DONT_KILL_APP ) and now my app is hidden from device. I cannot updated code from eclipse and there is no way to uninstall it. Is there way that i can programmatically re-enable my app and updated my code by installing from eclipse ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and there is no way to uninstall it

It should appear in the apps list in Settings, unless you're on 4.3, in which case there's a bug which means that it might not appear. In that case, use `adb uninstall your.package.name.here` to uninstall it. Or, if it's an emulator, start it manually from the AVD Manager, choosing "Wipe user data", to effectively factory-reset the emulator image.

Comment: I am using 4.1.2 and it is does not appear in apps list. Is there no way to programmatically enable it again ? Also it has an sms-receiver which starts app when an sms is received which is also not receiving sms broadcast after disabling app.

Comment: @rami: "I am using 4.1.2 and it is does not appear in apps list" -- it should. Note that disabled apps are listed separately at the end of the roster of installed apps. "Is there no way to programmatically enable it again ? " -- not that I am aware of. "Also it has an sms-receiver which starts app when an sms is received which is also not receiving sms broadcast after disabling app" -- that's because *you disabled the app*.